# how to configure class for mongo de/serialization

Tags: c#, mongodb, serialization, bson

I have a class:

```
class Product
{
    public String Name { get; private set; }
    private List<Release> releases;
    private List<Area> areas;

    public List<Release> Releases
    {
        get
        {
            return new List<Release>(releases);
        }
        private set
        {
            releases = value
        }
    }

    public List<Area> Area
    {
        get
        {
            return new List<Area>(areas);
        }
        private set
        {
            areas = value
        }
    }

    public Product(String Name)
    {
        this.Name = Name;
        this.Releases = new List<Release>();
        this.Areas = new List<Area>();
    }

    public Product(String Name, List<Release> Releases, List<Area> Areas)
    {
        this.Name = Name;
        this.Releases = Releases;
        this.Areas = Areas;
    }
}
```

My understanding is that Mongodb bson serializer will not be able to automatically de/serialize `Product` objects because all the properties/fields don't have public read and write access and I do not supply a no argument constructor. How could I go about configuring this to be fully de/serializable ? I have looked into the serialization tutorial on the mongodb.org but it didn't cover this scenario. I also found this https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/CSHARP-476 enhancement but it doesn't look to be implemented yet.

Currently I have another class `ProductDoc` which has the same field/properties but they have full public read and write access and I supply a no argument constructor so mongodb driver can automapp this type without any problems, and I just convert `Product` objects to `ProductDoc` objects and vice versa when I need to read write to the DB. But this seems very hacky even though it is very simple.

UPDATE:

It seems that it does not matter one jot that the set accessors on my public properties are private only that the property itself is public and the lack of a no-argument constructor doesn't seem to affect the de/serialization process either. Can anyone confirm how this works? and whether the info [here](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/CSharp+Driver+Quickstart#CSharpDriverQuickstart-DecideifyouwanttoworkwiththeBsonDocumentobjectmodelorwithyourowndomainclasses) is correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The quickstart tutorial is correct.  You can use private getters and setters for those.  But, if you are ever concerned, whipping up a test program to try stuff out is always the best answer.  The "public" read/write indicates that one of the getters or setters needs to be public.

Comment: I have whipped up a test program, and you are of course correct. I have since discovered the art of reflection.

Comment: Yes.  Reflection = awesome.  We have needed to use it abundantly in the mapping api as well as in our linq provider.  Be careful, as reflection is slow.  We have optimized in a number of places by compiling the getters and setters at runtime.  Have Fun!!!